# Is the dispatch_after method being executed concurrently in this code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, concurrency, timer

```
int total = 0;            // these are globals..
BOOL dispatchCalled = NO; //

-(void) callDispatch
{
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        dispatchCalled = YES;
        NSLog(@"Total, after 300ms, is %i", total);
    });
}

-(void)play // this is my "main" method..
{
    NSLog(@"app starts running");

    [self callDispatch];

    while(!dispatchCalled)
    {
        total++;
    }

    [self callDispatch];
 }
```

console :

```
   2012-08-02 20:36:05.357 MyProject[8245:1a07] app starts running
   2012-08-02 20:36:05.693 MyProject[8245:3d03] Total, after 300ms, is 11513522
   2012-08-02 20:36:05.993 MyProject[8245:3d03] Total, after 300ms, is 11513523
```

When the method enclosed in callDispatch is executed for the first time the while-loop has had time to execute 11513522 times. At that point the while-loop's condition is set to `YES` and the while-loop should execute no more. However, it is executed one more time before it acknowledges the updated by the dispatch method condition. Why is that?

Is it because the method enclosed in callDispatch will be executed **concurrently/in parallel** *with* the while loop, which would explain why it takes one more cycle for the while-loop to acknowledge the updated condition?

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside your `dispatch_after` block -- when it gets there, the debugger will tell you which thread it's on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is being run concurrently.  That means your block could execute at any given moment during the while loop, such as after passing the condition, but prior to incrementing the global, or after incrementing the global.  If you run your code multiple times, you'll notice that sometimes the `total` counts match, and sometimes they don't. *(Edit: This means your code is "nondeterministic" when run concurrently.)*

If you try to run your above code in a serial queue, the while-loop runs infinitely and no totals ever get printed.  In a serial queue, the block you schedule in callDispatch DOES get added to the queue to be called next, but given that the infinite loop never exits, nothing else in that queue will ever be called.

More info in Apple Doc: [GCD offers three different kinds of queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW2)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are effectively locking up the main event loop, then the queue that the blocks are being executed on must not be the main queue.

Therefore, you definitely have two threads running and, as such, there is no real guarantee how much time might pass between the first block and the second block executing.   As well, if dispatch_get_current_queue() happens to retrieve an asynchronous queue, you can assume nothing about the simultaneous execution of any blocks therein.

Or, to put it more bluntly:   You can't reason about execution and scheduling patterns in concurrent code;   you can't "play computer" and come up with anything but an approximation of what happened in one situation.

Comment: the way this code is written makes it so that the while loop doesn't immediately acknowledge the new condition, so it takes one more loop before it does that. Other than this minor defect, are you suggesting that this code can cause even greater inaccuracies or not? And in order to avoid such dangers, would running each method in a separate thread (or queue.. I'm still not sure about the difference..) solve this problem?